# Android convert JSONObject to HashMap and display in ListView with SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, json, listview

I try to search converting `JSONObject` to `HashMap` but most of the results are for Java not Android. Hence, I hope someone can share if you have experience in doing this before.

**listview_with_simpleAdapter_and_hashmap.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
    String[] food_id= new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
    String[] food_name = new String[]{"apple", "orange", "banana"};
    List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("ID", food_id[i]);
        hm.put("Name", food_name[i]);
        aList.add(hm);
    }

    String[] from = {"ID", "Name"};
    int[] to = {R.id.text_id, R.id.text_name};
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, aList, R.layout.list_item, from, to);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

**this file is working fine and simply display 2 columns in each row;**

[image]

**json.java**

```
TextView mTxtDisplay;
String url = "http://192.168.1.103/web_service/omg.php/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTxtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            mTxtDisplay.setText(response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

**192.168.1.103/web_service/omg.php/**

```
{
"32":"Western Food",
"35":"Japanese Food",
"37":"Italian Food"
}
```

JSON is working fine as well. The format is exactly the same as the `ListView` data -> ID and Name.

So my question is how to convert the `JSONObject` in *omg.php* to listview_with_simpleAdapter_and_hashmap.java ? I just need a simple example.

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28221555/how-does-okhttp-get-json-string/31762661#31762661

Comment: @codephillip that's not even Android - -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

// ...

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    try {
        Iterator<String> iterator = response.keys();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = iterator.next();
            String value = response.getString(key);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(KEY_ID, key);
            map.put(KEY_NAME, value);

            list.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(list.size() > 0) {
        String[] from = {KEY_ID, KEY_NAME};
        int[] to = {R.id.text_id, R.id.text_name};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, list,
            R.layout.list_item, from, to);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code to convert Jsonobject to hashmap

```
 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                try
                {

                   Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();

                    while (keys.hasNext())
                    {
                        String key = (String) keys.next();
                        String value = jsonObject.getString(key);
                        params.put(key, value);

                    }


                }
                catch (Exception xx)
                {
                    xx.toString();
                }
```